# How to access cluster_config dict within rule?

Tags: snakemake

I'm working on writing a benchmarking report as part of a workflow, and one of the things I'd like to include is information about the amount of resources requested for each job.

Right now, I can manually require the cluster config file ('cluster.json') as a hardcoded input. Ideally, though, I would like to be able to access the per-rule cluster config information that is passed through the --cluster-config arg. In **init**.py, this is accessed as a dict called `cluster_config`.

Is there any way of importing or copying this dict directly into the rule?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it looks like you can now use a custom wrapper script to access the job properties (including the cluster config data) when submitting the script to the cluster. Here is an example from [the documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executable.html#job-properties):

```py
#!python

#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

from snakemake.utils import read_job_properties

jobscript = sys.argv[1]
job_properties = read_job_properties(jobscript)

# do something useful with the threads
threads = job_properties[threads]

# access property defined in the cluster configuration file (Snakemake >=3.6.0)
job_properties["cluster"]["time"]

os.system("qsub -t {threads} {script}".format(threads=threads, script=jobscript))
```

During submission (last line of the previous example) you could either pass the arguments you want from the `cluster.json` to the script or dump the dict into a JSON file, pass the location of that file to the script during submission, and parse the json file inside your script.  Here is an example of how I would change the submission script to do the latter (untested code):

```py
#!python

#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import tempfile
import json

from snakemake.utils import read_job_properties

jobscript = sys.argv[1]
job_properties = read_job_properties(jobscript)

job_json = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.json')
json.dump(job_properties, job_json)

os.system("qsub -t {threads} {script} -- {job_json}".format(threads=threads, script=jobscript, job_json=job_json))
```

`job_json` should now appear as the first argument to the job script. Make sure to delete the `job_json` at the end of the job.

From a comment on another answer, it appears that you are just looking to store the `job_json` somewhere along with the job's output. In that case, it might not be necessary to pass `job_json` to the job script at all. Just store it in a place of your choosing.

Answer (score -1):

You can manage the resources for the cluster easily per Rules.

Indeed you have the **keyword "resources:"** to use like this :

```
rule one:
input:     ...
output:    ...
resources: 
    gpu=1,
    time=HH:MM:SS
threads: 4
shell: "..."
```

You can specify the resources by the yaml configuration files for the cluster give with the **parameter --cluster-config** like this:

```
rule one:
input:     ...
output:    ...
resources: 
    time=cluster_config["one"]["time"]
threads: 4
shell: "..."
```

When you will call snakemake you will just have to access to the resources like this (example for slurm cluster):

```
snakemake --cluster "sbatch -c {threads} -t {resources.time} " --cluster-config cluster.yml
```

It will send each rule with its specific resources for the cluster.

*For more informations, you can check the documentations with this link :* http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However, rather than accessing information for a particular rule at execution, I would like to access the entire dictionary in order to create a record of the resource requests. Do you know if this is possible?