# Properly accessing cluster_config '__default__' values

Tags: snakemake

I have a cluster.json file that looks like this:

```
{
    "__default__":
    {
        "queue":"normal",
        "memory":"12288",
        "nCPU":"1",
        "name":"{rule}_{wildcards.sample}",
        "o":"logs/cluster/{wildcards.sample}/{rule}.o",
        "e":"logs/cluster/{wildcards.sample}/{rule}.e",
        "jvm":"10240m"
    },
    "aln_pe":
    {
        "memory":"61440",
        "nCPU":"16"
    },
    "GenotypeGVCFs":
    {
        "jvm":"102400m",
        "memory":"122880"
    }
}
```

In my snakefile I have a few rules that try to access the cluster_config object in their params

```
params:
  memory=cluster_config['__default__']['jvm']
```

But this will give me a 'KeyError'

```
KeyError in line 27 of home/bwubb/projects/Germline/S0330901/haplotype.snake:
'__default__'
```

Does this have something to do with '__default__' being a special object? It pprints in a visually appealing dictionary where as the others are labeled OrderDict, but when I look at the json it looks the same.

If nothing is wrong with my json, then should I refrain from accessing '__default__'?

Answer (score 0):

The default value is accessed via the keyword "cluster", not

```
__default__
```

[See here in this example in the tutorial:](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/configuration.html#cluster-configuration)

```
{
"__default__" :
{
    "account" : "my account",
    "time" : "00:15:00",
    "n" : 1,
    "partition" : "core"
},
"compute1" :
{
    "time" : "00:20:00"
}
}
```

[The JSON list in the URL above and listed above is the one being accessed in this example. It's unfortunate they are not on the same page.
To access time, J.K. uses the following call.](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/executable.html?highlight=cluster%20config#cluster-execution)

```
#!python

#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

from snakemake.utils import read_job_properties

jobscript = sys.argv[1]
job_properties = read_job_properties(jobscript)

# do something useful with the threads
threads = job_properties[threads]

# access property defined in the cluster configuration file (Snakemake >=3.6.0)
job_properties["cluster"]["time"]

os.system("qsub -t {threads} {script}".format(threads=threads, script=jobscript))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I change to 

`memory=cluster_config['cluster']['jvm']`

I am met with a Key Error for 'cluster'

Comment: I apologize for my confusion but even after adding the read_job_properties it is still not clear what I am doing wrong.

my job_properties is None, even if I specifically state my jobscript.

Additionaly, I do not understand why I can access other parameters with cluster_config['rule'], but not the default in a similar way.

Comment: I actually didn't know that cluster_config worked at all. Curious though, why are you trying to access cluster level variables inside your rules. Wouldn't it be better to have cluster level configuration and rule level configuration separate? You want to pair the amount of memory requested from the cluster with the amount of memory requested by the (Java?) program you are running? Like -Xmx10240m ?

Comment: "...why are you trying to access cluster level variables inside your rules." Essentially what you deduced. I have a script to write my cluster.json in which I know what rules I want to run with more memory. I was under the impression that if I want -Xmx10240m I better request more then that from the cluster job. So I figured the easiest place to access the difference between cluster memory and jvm would be the cluster_config.

Comment: I learned about cluster_config from this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785833/how-to-access-cluster-config-dict-within-rule/44806073#44806073

Comment: It does not seem to be the best practice though I am still receiving KeyErrors for cluster_config, for keys that exist. Currently it is yelling at me that GenotypeGVCFs is a KeyError.